# uwsgi importing and pylance/pylint

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, uwsgi, pylint, pylance

If I use `import uwsgi` on my application I get an error on pylance, because uwsgi is only available on runtime (https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1073).

Is there a way to make this module available to linters like pylance/pylint? for now I'm using `# pylint: disable=import-error`, but that does not silence pylance and it still does not offer any autocompletion.

Comment: what's the error or warning when import uwsgi?

Comment: Whatever, you can set `"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {"reportMissingImports": "none" },` in Settings.json, the warning should go away. About no autocompletion, 1. check if you turn off the related settings. 2. the related docs and autocompletion may not be supported by Pylance, then you can file a report in [github-pylance](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues).

Comment: You misunderstood the question. As I said, the uwsgi module is only available on runtime because it's injected by the process. See for example https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1073

Answer (score -1):

pylint needs to be in the same virtualenv than your dependencies and be able to import them. Same for auto-completion, linters can't guess and needs to be able to access the library. So the solution would be to make `uwsgi` available in your dev environment (or at least the environment in which pylint is running).

Comment: The uwsgi module is only available at runtime since it's injected by the uwsgi process, so this won't work: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1073

Comment: I agree, it seems like it's a limitation with uwsgi that makes statistical analysis impossible.